# Why is my image sequence material node only uploading one image, even with properly named files?

Tags: animation, shaders, image, 2d, image-sequence

This is my first time asking a question here, so if there is any more information that you need from me please tell me.

If it matters as it pertains to this question, I use Blender on a 2023 iMac with the m3 chip.

So, I am working on a little mini version of myself and I want her to have a 2d face. I have been working on this for a while and I am running in to a bit of an issue here.
I am using an image sequence node, and I have my images numbered as newface.001.png,and new face.002.png with the .001 file representing the open eyes and .002 representing the closed eyes that I will animate to form a blink. I have tried uploading the images with newface001.png, new face_001.png, newface01.png, and almost every other variation of numbering the files. This results in a pink image for the second image texture, which tells me somehow the image data is lost somewhere. No matter how I number the files, this happens. This also happens when I start with a single image node and then add the second photo after switching the image node to be an image sequence node.

I also tried an alternative of connecting two single image node with a mix shader, with the intention to keyframe the mix shader. However, since the images have transparent backgrounds, I would have to connect both image alpha sockets to the PBSDF alpha socket, which is not possible since there is only one PBSDF alpha socket and two images. Not to mention, I also had to re unwrap the faces and UVmap them over each time I tried to switch from one image to the next. It got really tiring after a month. I hope this makes sense.

I also thought that an alternative to this would be to match hex codes. So I matched each of the images backgrounds to the exact color of the body material so that it would appear transparent without actually being transparent. In theory that would have solved the issue. However, the matching hex code image just does not appear transparent because of the way the light interacts with both the material and the image. It looks close but is visibly off, even with adjustments. On top of that, the second image still does not show up.

I was hoping someone could help me out with this because I have a lot of cool ideas I want to do with this and I just can't figure it out after a month.

(The visible image in the photo set is prior to UV unwrapping.)

[image: material screenshot]

[image: filenames]

[image: pinkfaceofdoom]

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to activate the *Auto Refresh* option, put *Frames* at 1 as you want only one frame to be played, put *Offset* at 0 if you want to display the first picture, keyframe the *Offset*:

[image]

Move forwards in your *Timeline*. To switch to the second picture, put the *Offset* at 1 and keyframe. Choose a *Constant* interpolation between the keyframes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now I feel a little silly that it seemed like I missed such a big thing for so long. You've solved my issue!